# HTML table for use in medical diagnostics

Tags: html, html-table

I am trying to reproduce the following table in HTML [image]

I have reached the following structure with the following code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.vertical-text {
 transform: rotate(270deg);
 transform-origin: left top 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<table>
 <caption>Stadializarea nefropatiei diabetice</caption>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="11">60</td>
   <th colspan="4"></th>
   <th colspan="4">Persistent albuminuria categories<br>Description and range
  </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4">Stadializarea CKD in functie<br> de filtrarea glomerulara si albuminurie</td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td colspan="4"></td>
   <td>Jill</td>
   <td>Smith</td>
   <td>50</td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td>G1</td>  
   <td>Normal of high</td>
   <td>>90</td>
   <td>Stadiu</td>
   <td bgcolor="red"></td>
   <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
   <td bgcolor="orange"></td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td>G1</td>  
   <td>Normal of high</td>
   <td>>90</td>
   <td>Stadiu</td>
   <td bgcolor="red"></td>
   <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
   <td bgcolor="orange"></td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td>G1</td>  
   <td>Normal of high</td>
   <td>>90</td>
   <td>Stadiu</td>
   <td bgcolor="red"></td>
   <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
   <td bgcolor="orange"></td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td>G1</td>  
   <td>Normal of high</td>
   <td>>90</td>
   <td>Stadiu</td>
   <td bgcolor="red"></td>
   <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
   <td bgcolor="orange"></td>   
  </tr>
<tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td>G1</td>  
   <td>Normal of high</td>
   <td>>90</td>
   <td>Stadiu</td>
   <td bgcolor="red"></td>
   <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
   <td bgcolor="orange"></td>   
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>60</td> 
   <td>G1</td>  
   <td>Normal of high</td>
   <td>>90</td>
   <td>Stadiu</td>
   <td bgcolor="red"></td>
   <td bgcolor="blue"></td>
   <td bgcolor="orange"></td>   
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</html>
```

But I can not:
 - merge the nine cells of the first column (with the 60s) with the nine cells of the second column (and eliminate their left and upper border);
 - merge the cells 10-15 of the first column, so I can enter some vertical text in there;

without altering the current layout. I appreciate any suggestion. Is there an easier way than a html table to implement this?

Comment: `<div>` tags can be more flexible, possibly. But this is totally do-able in a `table` using the appropriate `rowspan` and `colspan` attributes. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: You want a table of 7 x 10 cells, and then group certain cells with the row- and col- span attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the starting HTML you need:

```css
table, td {
border:1px solid #999;
}

td {
width: 50px;
height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td colspan="4" rowspan="4"></td>
  <td colspan="3"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>A1</td>
  <td>A2</td>
  <td>A3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td rowspan="6"></td>
  <td>G1</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>G2</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>G3a</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>G3b</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>G4</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>G5</td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ohhhh bummer you beat me!
With the following css you merge the cell borders: `table{border-collapse: collapse;}`

Comment: AFAIK I did not downvote anything. This was the why I also did it, but not fast enough :) I gave you an upvote now to undo the anonymous downvoter.